Docker volume only works if all files match
The only way I can get it to work if I use a bind mount volume that connects both of the containers totally, when I remove it it doesnt work. Without the shared volume between frontend and backend they both can't communicate. They are also both on the same network.
UPDATED with no volumes, dockerfiles, nginx config, sample call and error message (2nd update added proxy from nginx to php-fpm which is on port 9000)
Compose:
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - api
    links:
      - api
    develop:
      watch:
        - path: .
          target: /var/www/html
          action: sync

  api:
    build:
      context: ./libs/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"


Dockerfiles
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY --chown=nginx:nginx ./conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/

COPY --chown=nginx:nginx . /var/www/html


FROM php:8.2-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html   

ARG UID=101
ARG GID=101

//just updating user and group to same as nginx user on frontend
RUN groupadd -g "${GID}" php-fpm \
    && useradd --no-log-init -u "${UID}" -g "${GID}" php-fpm \
    && chown php-fpm:php-fpm -R /var/www/html

USER php-fpm


COPY --chown=php-fpm:php-fpm . .


Request made from jquery script:
$("#submit_1").on("click", () => {
  const inputVal = $("#input_1").val();

   $.ajax({
      url: "/api/",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        searchTerm: inputVal,
      },
      method: "POST",

      success: (results) => console.log(results),
      error: (obj, details) => console.log(obj, details),
    });
  }
});

Nginx default.conf
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name api;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api:9000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Enable CORS headers
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type";
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}



├── docker-compose.yaml
├── index.html 
└── libs/
    ├── php/
    │   ├── geocodeBackend.php   # PHP files served by php-fpm
    │   └── other_php_files.php
    ├── js/
    │   └── jquery.js            # JS, Css and html served by nginx
    └── css/
        └── styles.css   

Error:

web-1   | 2024/11/03 00:58:59 [error] 30#30: *5 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: api, request: "POST /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:9000/", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"


web-1   | 172.18.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2024:00:58:59 +0000] "POST /api HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0" "-"

PHP-FPM container has its file
root@124743cd5330:/var/www/html# ls
Dockerfile  geocodeBackend.php



NGINX has its
root@b4eba721669f:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
50x.html      compose.dev.yaml  favicon.ico  libs
README.Docker.md  conf.d        index.html   root


UPDATE  (it works)
Thanks to changing the nginx default.conf files correctly and updating the js script url to /api/ (extra slash at the end). Below is everything I changed!
default.conf
server {
    listen 8080;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name api;
    root  /var/www/html/;

    location /api/ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME geocodeBackend.php;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
    }
}

script.js
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        searchTerm: inputVal,
      },
      method: "POST",


This has nothing to do with "containers" and everything to do with nginx making requests to FPM about files that FPM and/or your app code can't find on its side. The files don't "have to match" but you need to make sure that you're mapping requests properly which will require additional nginx and/or FPM config and/or app config. The default assumption is that nginx and FPM are using the same working directory.

Hard for me to understand tbh. The 1st container configuration works so it must have something to do with the bind mount. Otherwise the 2nd would work too right?

What happens if you delete the volumes: entirely, so that the setup is independent of any files that exist on this particular host system?  (Do you COPY the source files into your images?)  What does the Nginx configuration look like, and what's a sample call that doesn't work?

@DavidMaze I did an update with all the info you requested. Let me know what you think and thanks!


But after trying for hours the only option is to put it all into the same exact folder in volume which defeats the purpose of containerization.

This is due to the try_files $uri =404; directive in your nginx config. You don't need to use it at all. Here is documentation on that directive.

web-1 | 2024/11/03 00:58:59 [error] 30#30: *5 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: api, request: "POST /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:9000/", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"

This is because you are trying to communicate with your PHP-FPM backend via HTTP protocol while it is expects FastCGI one.
As far as I understand, if you want to pass all /api... requests to the geocodeBackend.php PHP script, you need something like
location /api {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /full/path/to/geocodeBackend.php;
    fastcgi_pass api:9000;
}

(BTW, I recommend to use /api/... rather than /api...).
Some PHP scripts may additionally rely on some other FastCGI variables like SCRIPT_NAME, DOCUMENT_URI or DOCUMENT_ROOT; see the last part of this answer and comment below for more information.

WOW that worked! Thanks so much! Why does that work? I'm having a really hard time understanding how fast_cgi works, I thought I could just send a request to the backend like normal? I've updated the post with the what I changed. could you help me to understand how that works? If not, maybe an article?

Ok nevermind I think I get it! PHP-FPM is not set to handle HTTP requests so the proxy would result in the errors. This whole directive is pointing any requests to /api/ as a FastCGI formatted request to my api:9000. fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME geocodeBackend.php is where these request point to. With try_files $uri =404;  when  the exact path isn’t found in the nginx directory, Nginx will return a 404 error instead of automatically forwarding the request to geocodeBackend.php. Is this correct?

Sorry for a late response, yes, in general it is correct (some points need to be clarified, e.g. "nginx directory" - check nginx -V response to find out the  precompiled prefix value). I'm going to add some details to the answer, however didn't have a time for it right now, sorry :(
